# Pegar o valor de um form que tem uma lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, button

Galera tudo bem? sou eu de novo, sei que estou fazendo muitas perguntas, mas estou com umas dúvidas e não encontro resposta, estou querendo capturar o evento de um botão em asp.net mvc utilizando razor, estou com o seguinte botão:

```
<input type="button" value="Salvar" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("insert")'" />
```

e este é o meu código do *controller*

```
    public ActionResult insert()
    {
        myMetodInsert();//futuro método que ira inserir dados na base
        return List();
    }
```

O método retorna um outro método `List` que retorna uma *view*, porém percebi que ele tenta acessar uma página com o nome do método, mas essa não é a intenção. A intenção é chamar um método que irá incluir dados no banco e depois retornar a página. Poderiam ajudar?

---

**Edit**

A questão é a seguinte: eu abro uma página com uma lista de mercadorias, onde a pessoa pode mudar apenas o valor da mercadoria. Essa lista contém no seu primeiro elemento um campo seleção com `checkbox` (com valor `boolean` na mesma).

Assim que a pessoa marca o `checkbox`, ele habilita a edição. No momento que a pessoa clicar no botão **salvar**, eu devo capturar esse evento, receber essa lista modificada e persistir a modificação no banco.

Estou com dúvida apenas na captura do evento. Quando eu usava java com JSF, bastava colocar o *bean* + método no botão que ele identificava isso. No asp.net MVC não tem algo parecido?

Para maior esclarecimento segue o código como esta:

View

```
@model Teste.Models.Produto

@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "ListaProdutoCab", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selecione</th>
                <th>Produto</th>
                <th>Valor</th>

            </tr>
        </thead> @foreach (var item in Model.listaBebida)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.isEditado)</td>
                <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.produto, new { disabled = "disabled" }) </td>
                <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.valor) </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <div id="modal">
        <div id="botoes">
            <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Meu Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Teste.DAO;
using Teste.Models;

namespace Teste.Controllers
{
    public class ListaProdutoCab: Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ListaProdutoCab/
        ListaProdutoService service = new ListaProdutoService();
        Produto produto = new Produto();
        Session usuario = new Session("Genisson", 058);

        List<ObjectMasterProduto> listaProduto= new List<ObjectMasterProduto>();

        public ActionResult ListaProdutoCab()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult List()

        {
            service.carregarListaBebida(produto.listaBebida);
            return PartialView(produto);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Salvar()
        {
            service.Salvar(produto.listaBebida, usuario);
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }

    }
}
```

Produto

```
 public class Produto
    {

        //Chamadas externas
        public Bebida bebida{ get; set; }

        public List<Bebida> listaBebida{ get; set; }

        public Produto()
        {

        }


    }
```

Classe bebida

```
public class bebida
    {

        //Chamadas externas
        public String nome{ get; set; }

        public Double Valor{ get; set; }

        public Bebida()
        {

        }


    }
```

Da para fazer o que eu preciso só utilizando api nativa do asp.net mvc? ou precisarei realmente utilizar outras api's?

Comment: Não seria melhor usar Ajax pra fazer isso que você quer?

Comment: Concordo com o  @CiganoMorrisonMendez , use o AJAX.

Comment: Altera a pergunta e coloca a estrutura da classe `Produto` que eu faço outra resposta mais adequada para responder a sua pergunta.

Comment: Pergunta agora esta alterada com a classe produto e bebida

Answer (score 1):

Se você vai utilizar um formulário para inserir dados, você deve colocar o tipo do `button` como `submit`.

Se for esse o caso, tente fazer algo assim:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "Algum", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="nome" />
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
}
```

E no controller faça algo assim:

```
public class AlgumController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Salvar(string nome)
    {
        Respositorio.Salvar(nome);
        return RedirectToAction("Listar");
    }

    public ActionResult Listar()
    {
        var lista = Repositorio.Listar();

        return View("Lista", lista);
    }
}
```

Fazendo isso o método `Salvar` vai receber o valor nome correspondente ao `input` HTML e irá chamar um método para realizar a ação de salvamento. Após salvar o método retorna um `RedirectToAction` que irá redirecionar para o método `Listar`.

**Edição:**

Se você estiver usando jQuery no seu projeto você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$('#meu-btn').on('click', function()
{
    var dadosParaSalvar = coletarDadosDaTabela();

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: 'Algum/Salvar', //'Controller/Action'
        data: { dados: dadosParaSalvar },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.error == undefined || response.success) {
                try {
                    //Válido apenas se você retornar a lista como JSON, utilizando JsonResult,
                    //caso contrário deve-se utilizar o JSON.parse('string')
                    var lista = response;

                    consumirListaDeRetorno(lista);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    Erro(err);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

E no `controller` para receber os dados enviados por `ajax` e retornar um `JSON` faça como a seguir:

```
public class AlgumController : Controller
{
    //Todos os registros que forem passados para uma action, desde que possuam o tipo correto
    //e o mesmo nome são encapsulados automáticamente em uma classe modelo, como a classe 'ClasseModelo'.
    //Se todos os dados possuirem corretamente as propriedades presentes na classe 'ClasseModelo', o array passado
    //utilizando ajax será automáticamente convertido para uma List<ClasseModelo>.
    public ActionResult Salvar(IList<ClasseModelo> dados)
    {
        //Aqui você adiciona a lógica para o salvamento das informações
        Respositorio.Salvar(dados);
        //Aqui você gera uma lista atualizada dos dados que deseja retornar
        var listaAtualizada = Repositorio.Listar();

        //Aqui você passa o objeto 'listaAtualizada' como primeiro parâmetro para que
        //ele seja serializado no formano JSON para o retorno.
        //O segundo parâmetro permite que o retorno JSON seja permitido utilizando o método HTTP GET
        return Json(listaAtualizada , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Assim você coletará os dados utilizando `JavaScript`, enviará para o seu `controller` utilizando o `Ajax`, processará os dados no `controller` e retornará um `JSON` para que o `callback success` do `ajax` utilize a listade retorno.

Comment: Acho que o que ele quer é chamar um JS e receber a lista por um `JsonResult`.

Comment: Não tenho certeza disso, por isso sugeri essa opção. Ele fala que quer retornar uma página. Se for esse o caso e ele deixar clara esta intenção eu modifico a resposta incrementando com a opção para um retorno JSON.

Comment: Ele editou a pergunta. Acho que é isso mesmo.

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de pegar o objeto em sessão (no caso a lista) no meu controller sem ter que usar Jquery ou ajax? estive tentando pegar a lista que está iniciada em sessão, mas ao chamar o controller ele executa todas as variáveis, assim não consigo pegar a minha lista já carregada e com os campos modificados que esta na minha view, se não for possível estarei utilizando a solução proposta.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem o questionamento, mas ao alterar na view (utilizando um browser por exemplo) os dados não são modificados na sessão, pelo menos não sem utilizar javascript. Se você só quiser alterar os valores da lista na sessão e depois retornar a lista que está na sessão, isso pode ser feito.

Comment: então a minha duvida é totalmente essa, eu quero salvar as alterações dessa lista que eu carreguei no controller, pois o campo 'valor' esta habilitado para tal feito, então quando por exemplo, trazer o produto coca-cola com o valor de 4,75, o usuario pode mudar por exemplo nessa lista o valor para 5,00, se ele clicar em salvar, minha action salvar deve pegar essa lista que esta na sessão e passar ela como parametro pro meu metodo ''salvar'' do meu service, não sei se ficou meio confuso mas é isso. se tem como pode me indicar algum tutorial ou mostrar como?

Comment: Entendi, porém acho que você está vendo o funcionamento do ASP.NET MVC de forma incorreta. Quando você retorna a sua lista para uma view e ela é exibida para o usuário ela não fica armazenada em sessão. E as alterações que o usuário faz não são refletidas na sua lista no controller. Essas alterações realizadas pelo usuário são envidas para o controller utilizando os métodos HTTP. Então o certo é você utilizar um `<form>` ou `ajax`. O MVC permite que você utilize um "form ajax" para fazer isso que você deseja sem recarregar a página.

Comment: já estou utilizando o form, conforme o código que postei acima, apenas gostaria de saber como receber essa lista que estou exibindo no form, e como receber ela como um parametro no meu actionResult salvar

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal depois de algum tempo pesquisando, descobri que o foreach não é muito recomendável nesse caso, pois o mesmo duplica os id's e deixa invalido a nível de html. a propriedade disable faz os valores retornarem null do form, a solução foi alterar de foreach para for e trocar disable por readonly, obrigado pessoal.